# trouble obtaining the same hash of a file on server as on the client

Tags: node.js, hash, sveltekit, node-forge

I would like to obtain the **same hash** of a file on *server* as on the *client*.

I tried:

1. creating a form to upload
2. computing the hash with `node-forge` client-side
3. computing the hash on Linux command-line
4. uploading the file through the form
5. grabbing the file server-side as a blob
6. reading contents with .text() server-side
7. computing the hash server-side with `node-forge`

I am stuck at 7.

So, first I upload a file through a form

```html
<form method="POST" action="?/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input
            id="csvFile"
            name="csvFile"
            type="file"
            on:change={handleChange}
        />
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Upload</button>
</form>
```

and I compute the hash of a file in the browser with `node-forge`:

```js
function handleChange(event) {
        let files = event.target.files;
        const file = files[0]
                reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (event) {
                var binary = event.target.result;
            var md = forge.md.sha256.create();
            sha256 = md.update(binary).digest().toHex();
        };
                reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
}
```

This computes a hash that is the same as when I execute it from the command line with `sha256sum`, so it is reliable.

However, when I upload the file and process it on SvelteKit, I am unable to obtain the same hash. I am thinking this is because the filename or something else is missing from the resulting blob compared to what is available in the browser.

```js
export const actions = {
    upload: async ({ request }) => {
        const formData = await request.formData()
        const file = await formData.get(`csvFile`) as File;
        const contents = await file.text()

        const md = forge.md.sha256.create();
        md.update(contents);
        const sha256 = md.digest().toHex()
    }
}
```

I cannot use `new FileReader()` here because I am in a Node environment.

How can I create the exact same hash server-side and client-side? Do I need to add the filename or something to obtain the same hash as from the command line?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Reading as text implies some encoding. The best approach is probably to read the data as simple array buffers in both cases to be consistent.

You can use the asynchronous [`arrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer) function on the file in both cases. (If you want to target older browsers, you can also use `FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()` on the client.)

In both cases you can convert the data to a hash-able string, e.g. by converting the individual bytes and joining them:

```js
const content = [...new Uint8Array(fileArrayBuffer)]
    .map(b => String.fromCharCode(b))
    .join('');
```

Comment: This gives me just another hash, but not the same hash as the command-line `sha256sum` utility. I did `const ab = await file.arrayBuffer();  b = Buffer.from(ab); contents = [...new Uint8Array(b)].map((b) => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join(''); const md = forge.md.sha256.create();
        md.update(contents);
        const sha256 = md.digest().toHex()

Comment: Of course you get a different hash. This converts the data to a hex string because the function *only accepts strings*. `Buffer.from` is redundant, by the way, you already have a buffer that can be used in `Uint8Array`. Why do you care about the command line value? The important part should be that client and server produce the same hash, what are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: (To get a pure binary string you probably could map the bytes via `b => String.fromCharCode(b)`; unless JS does some additional magic, that should yield the exact contents as a string. If that does not work, you probably have to look into how to pass binary directly to the hashing functions.)

Comment: thanks for your last hint. Mapping the bytes worked.

Comment: could you explain what the encoding is of the different steps in your answerd? So first you have a blob (which encoding is this?), then you get an ArrayBuffer (is this hexadecimal or binary), then you turn it into an array of bytes (UTF-16) and then you convert the bytes with String.fromCharCode to a normal string?

Comment: Do you know why it is necessary to do all this transformation? And why it is not possible to just use blob.text()?

Comment: There is no encoding at all, that is the whole point. A blob is binary, buffers are binary, Uint8Arrays are binary and the resulting string is also just binary but each 8-bit value is stored in an up to 16-bit character unit. The problem with `text()` is, that it has encoding which partitions multiple bytes into characters, so certain sequences of bytes are interpreted together which apparently can affect the hashing algorithm. [Here is an example](https://svelte.dev/repl/b73873f828714c3aa55850cf827d92c4?version=3.52.0) that illustrates how the buffer approach separates the underlying bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The SvelteKit POST page endpoint had to do a mapping:

File (Blob) -> ArrayBuffer (raw binary data) -> UInt8Array -> Utf-16 Array -> String

```js
async upload({ request }) {
        const formData = await request.formData();
        const blob = formData.get('csvFile');
        const ab = await blob.arrayBuffer()
        const contents = [...new Uint8Array(ab)]
            .map((b) => String.fromCharCode(b))
            .join('');
        const md = forge.md.sha256.create();
        md.update(contents);
        const sha256 = md.digest().toHex()
```

Thanks to @H.B. for the hints.

Comment: `Buffer.from` is still redundant. There also is no need to post additional answers on your questions if the existing answers, like mine, answer the overall question. Also, you should accept answers on your questions, there appear to be several that could have accepted answers.

Comment: Hi @H.B. , I have added this answer because I would not be able to reproduce this code within a year with your answer and the comments alone. Your answer was very helpful though when I was still within the zone of that part of my code.